# Issue in splitting the routes file in play framework 2.2.6 java

Tags: playframework-2.2

I want to Split my play routes files into two different file.
I have **conf/routes** and **conf/admin.routes** as two routes file in conf folder. In routes file I have specified   **-> /admin  admin.Routes** but Play is unable to resolve Routes.

Is there any other way to include other routes file in build.at or any other workaround which works for Play(Java).

Comment: To divide the routes in two files you need to split your project into modules,  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTSubProjects